# Inputstream, Can't read commas ' or quotes "" in android

Tags: android, text, inputstream

I am trying to read a text file from raw folder, and it works perfectly except for one problem.

The problem is for any quotes " ", or Commas ' in the text file, it displays this question mark symbol instead.

code:

```
try {
        Resources res = getResources();
        InputStream in_s = res.openRawResource(R.raw.hr_consultant);

        byte[] b = new byte[in_s.available()];

        
        in_s.read(b);

        tv_data.setText(new String(b));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // e.printStackTrace();
        tv_data.setText("Error: can't show help.");
    }
```

N.B: the text file in raw is referred as int value, so another Reader types may not work. so
any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you done with your text file;

- Select File > Save As
- Edit "Encoding" property to UTF-8